# INNER JOIN works as SELECT but not as DELETE

Tags: mysql, sql

Why does this have a syntax error

```
DELETE FROM `print_mailing_request` pmr
INNER JOIN `person` p
  ON p.id = pmr.person AND p.email LIKE '%@TEST.COM'
WHERE 
pmr.sent_to_fulfiller != 'y'
```

when this works correctly without error?

```
SELECT * FROM `print_mailing_request` pmr
INNER JOIN `person` p
  ON p.id = pmr.person AND p.email LIKE '%@TEST.COM'
WHERE 
pmr.sent_to_fulfiller != 'y'
```

Comment: Are you trying to delete data from both tables?

Comment: Since one is SQL Server 2008 and mine is mySQL (tagged but not explicitly stated) I wasn't sure that post was relevent to mine and moreover I tried to implement that solution...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax would look like below without using table alias. You are missing the table name to delete from.

```
DELETE `print_mailing_request`
FROM `print_mailing_request`
INNER JOIN `person` 
  ON `person`.id = `print_mailing_request`.person 
  AND `person`.email LIKE '%@TEST.COM'
WHERE `print_mailing_request`.sent_to_fulfiller != 'y'
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to tell `delete` what table to delete from:

```
DELETE pmr
    FROM `print_mailing_request` pmr INNER JOIN
         `person` p
         ON p.id = pmr.person AND p.email LIKE '%TEST.COM'
    WHERE pmr.sent_to_fulfiller != 'y';
```

The table alias goes after the `delete` statement and before the `from`.  I am assuming it is the first table mentioned.